# c# изменение значений combobox и проверка

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox, textbox

Всем привет.

Нужна помощь.

Имеется:

- textbox для поиска значений
- datagridview для отображения найденных значений
- combobox для выбора значения

Ну и кнопка для добавления в базу выбранных данных

Собственно вопрос: Если значение в textbox'е не имеется в базе, то бьет ошибку и combobox становится пустой. Как можно реализовать проверку на подобие: если textbox пуст или не имеется данных в datagrid, то принудительно выбирать,например, 4-е значение в combobox ?

Спасибо за помощь!

[image: Картинка]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: if (textbox.text == String.Empty) combobox.SelectedIndex = 4; или в блоке catch делать присвоение  combobox.SelectedIndex = 4;  но лучше иметь какое - то значение по умолчанию и его выбирать, дабы избежать "МАГИЧЕСКИХ ЧИСЕЛ", как это сделано в моем примере))) Спасибо за понимание!

Comment: @Dude36 к сожалению, не помогает данный способ. иногда пользователи вводят данные, они, по факту, есть в строке, но нет в базе.

Comment: Понял, вывод самих данных куда происходить? либо обрабатывать combobox перед выводом сообщения. если можно, то кусок кода в студию ?

Comment: `if (результат_из_БД == пусто) comboBox.SelectedIndex = 4`